# Why did Zordan Stark (captain of U-2501) decide to sink Takao in chapter 37?

Tags: arpeggio-of-blue-steel

In depth 37 (chapter 37), Zordan Stark and U-2501 plans to sink Takao. However, I am not clear on what the purpose of this act was.

Can anyone explain clearly to me? It would be great if you have any evidence (from the manga).